Minimax for tictactoe placing multiple values at once
I am trying to write a TicTacToe game with a minimax ai in JS.
However my minimax function just does not work. I used timeouts to see what happened every function call and discovered that the function placed multiple tiles at once and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
P.S if you have any refactoring or any other changes that could be made feel free.
Here is the github link in case you want to see the output with the page: https://github.com/guerlain-hitier/TicTacToeAI
var board = [
    [],
    [],
    []
];

const human = 'X';
const ai = 'O';
var player = human;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    let currentRow = Array.from(document.getElementById('row' + (i +1)).children);

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        board[i].push(currentRow[j]);
        board[i][j].innerText = '';
        board[i][j].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            place(getPos(event.target), player);
            player = ai;
            place(bestMove(), player);
            player = human;
        });
    }
}

function bestMove() {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let move;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].innerText === '') {
                board[i][j].innerText = ai;
                let score = minimax(board, 0, false);
                board[i][j].innerText = '';
                if (score > bestScore) {
                    bestScore = score;
                    move = {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return move;
}

values = {
    X: -1,
    O: 1,
    tie: 0
}

async function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
    let result = checkWinner();
    if (result !== null) {
        return values[result];
    }

    if (isMaximizing) {
        let bestScore = -Infinity;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j].innerText === '') {
                    board[i][j].innerText = ai;
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false);
                    board[i][j].innerText = '';
                    bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);

                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    } else {
        let bestScore = Infinity;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j].innerText === '') {
                    board[i][j].innerText = human;
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0));
                    let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true);
                    board[i][j].innerText = '';
                    bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                }
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
}

function place(pos, player) {
    board[pos.y][pos.x].innerText = player;
}

function getPos(target) {
    let x = target.id[3] - 1;
    let y = target.parentElement.id[3] - 1;
    return {x, y};
}

function resetBoard(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j].innerText = '';
        }
    }
    player = 'X';
}

function checkWinner(){
    // Check rows
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[i][0].innerText === board[i][1].innerText && board[i][1].innerText === board[i][2].innerText && board[i][0].innerText !== '') {
            return board[i][0].innerText;
        }
    }

    // Check columns
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (board[0][i].innerText === board[1][i].innerText && board[1][i].innerText === board[2][i].innerText && board[0][i].innerText !== '') {
            return board[0][i].innerText;
        }
    }

    // Check diagonals
    if (board[0][0].innerText === board[1][1].innerText && board[1][1].innerText === board[2][2].innerText && board[0][0].innerText !== '') {
        return board[0][0].innerText;
    }

    if (board[0][2].innerText === board[1][1].innerText && board[1][1].innerText === board[2][0].innerText && board[0][2].innerText !== '') {
        return board[0][2].innerText;
    }

    return null;
}



I tried to add console logs and look at the function itself but I just don't know. I also tried to rewrite everything to see if I had done something wrong earlier but to no avail.

All of the id tags in a page are supposed to be unique.  You have multiple box1 tags.

In bestMove, you need to set move = {x:i, y:j};.  Your place routine assumes that structure.  Also, bestMove never checks if the board is already full.

As a general rule, minimax sucks for tic-tac-toe.  It just fills the cells in order across and down, because it's not doing any assessment of the "quality" of an intermediate position,
